# How to prevent WebStorm 2016.2 Babel plugin from compiling in certain directories?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, babeljs

I've enabled the Babel File Watcher, as described [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/).

It does its job, but also seems to get active in places I don't want - my `app/lib`, `server` and `node_modules` folders.

The Webstorm blog (link above) suggests making a separate "Scope" that would exclude unwanted directories. I'm looking for other solutions, since:

- I would prefer the solution to be in version controlled files, not the WebStorm preferences

I tried setting up `.babelrc` as such:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules/**",
    "app/lib/**",
    "server/**"
  ]
}
```

This did not change the behaviour.

I presume the Babel "presets" system cannot be overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution is using scopes as suggested in blog - when using default scope (Project Files) Babel watcher listens to all .js files in your project. So, Babel will be started for all them - and `.babelrc` is checked once the process is started, not before starting it.
Scopes are stored with project, in .idea folder. If you like to version control scopes, use 'shared' type - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/scope.html#d317067e51